# How to write commands with default variables for terminal or default app (Browser, Terminal) so it would work on any Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, kubuntu, mate

How to write commands with default variables for terminal or default app (Browser, Terminal) so it would work on any Ubuntu or Debian?

For example Ubuntu mate has mate-terminal
How to write commands that would open in each distro with befault terminal and browser? So in this command line wouldnt be mate-terminal and firefox but some wrapper of them for any distro user default apps of terminal or browser.

```
mate-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; dpkg -S "\/bin/$(xprop WM_CLASS | cut -d "\"" -f2)"; sleep 5; firefox'
```

how to find default app variables or wrappers so that command would be running in any distro terminal apps? How to find also default browser or text editor variables?

Comment: That is theoretically impossible because for any strategy you come up with, someone could create a Ubuntu or Debian based distribution your strategy doesn't work with. Please be more specific about your actual goal. Regarding default applications, take a look at `xdg-open` and `xdg-mime`, but those are only really helpful if the distribution in question is (at least to some extend) xdg compliant.

Comment: Most of them should set `x-terminal-emulator` to the distro's default terminal emulator via the `update-alternatives` mechanism

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run the same command on multiple platforms / distributions there is a workaround which involves writing customized copies of the same command and separating them with the `||` operator which will try to execute the next command if the first command fails.

## Example

Command for `mate-terminal`:

```
mate-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox'
```

Command for `gnome-terminal`:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox'
```

Command that will run on either terminal:

```
mate-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox' || gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox'
```

Command that will run on either terminal and launch either `firefox`, `google-chrome` or `chromium`:

```
mate-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox || google-chrome || chromium' || gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'sleep 2; echo "hi"; sleep 5; firefox || google-chrome || chromium'
```

This will however require looking into target platforms to find out how to correctly run the command.

Best of luck

Comment: Command would be used for any distro, but user might have different apps and chrome or chromium and not firefox.

Comment: @Kangarooo Then you would write a copy of the command for each app `chromium`, `chrome` and `firefox` ... etc and separate them with `||`. Otherwise I can't think of other ways right now.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about how different distribution set their preferred apps for web browser and terminal emulator, but I do for Xfce desktop environment. Maybe you can do the same with other DEs, if you install `exo-utils` package.

The preferred applications would be set by running

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

and your example command (purpose of which is unknown to me) would be formulated like this:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator bash -c 'sleep 2; dpkg -S "\/bin/$(xprop WM_CLASS | cut -d "\"" -f2)"; sleep 5; exo-open --launch WebBrowser; read'
```

`read` is needed because the web browser might close with the terminal window.

Comment: Oh, wow. How to find all alternatives? What they are called like? Wrappers of commands?

Comment: @Kangarooo `man exo-open`

Answer (score 0):

Here is rewrite of your command using Debian's alternatives system:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c 'sleep 2; dpkg -S "\/bin/$(xprop WM_CLASS | cut -d "\"" -f2)"; sleep 5; x-www-browser'
```

Note the use of `-e` for the command the terminal emulator should run.

If you would like to change the default terminal emulator you would run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Respectively, to change the default web browser you would run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

Comment: how to see other wrappers or how to call them?

Comment: @Kangarooo Type `sudo update-alternatives --config` (without pressing Enter) in terminal and press Tab key three times to complete. You can call the wrappers by their names since their symbolic links are found in PATH. See also `man update-alternatives`.